# React multiple .map

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a data structure like: `[{category:'Category1', products:[{name:'Product1', price:10},{name:'Product2', price:20}]}]`. What I want to do is to render a list of products but also use the Category as the Subheader of the list. I was thinking about using .map function inside another .map, as showed bellow, but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
getList(){
  return (
    this.props.data.map(category =>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <Subheader title={category.category} />
          {category.products.map(product => <li>{product.name}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the <div> in the code (already edited) but still not working

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? It gives an error or doesn't render anything or what?

Comment: It doesn't  render

Answer (score 1):

It works fine, as you can see from the following output:

```js
// Sample component and data:
const Subheader = props => (<h1>{props.title}</h1>);
const category = {category:'Category1', products:[{name:'Product1', price:10},{name:'Product2', price:20}]};

// Render:
ReactDOM.render(
  (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <Subheader title={category.category} />
        {category.products.map(product => (<li>{product.name}</li>))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  ),
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't see the expected result, check the `props.data`.

Comment: The subheader is working well. I switche the `ListItem` tag for a `li` but it's rendering only the bullet points, no text

Comment: @ThiagoNascimento Can you log `props.data` to the console and include the output in your question? Also, could you show the updated code with the `<li>` elements?

Comment: The data I posted in the question was taken from the console. As for the li, I edited the inicial post

Comment: @ThiagoNascimento I updated the answer, everything seems fine - the issue is probably with `props.data`. Can you add a `console.log(props.data)` call to your `getList` function?

Comment: @ThiagoNascimento Can you also show us how you render the result of the `getList()` output? Also, could you check the developer console (press F12) whether the text is in the DOM?